# Drawer usage in Compose Material3

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Is there a way to have the menu overlap the header and footer here?

I am using `androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold` and `NavigationDrawer`.

It seems like the Scaffold's drawer slot is removed - https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1896804 so the instructions at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material?hl=hu#drawers no longer apply.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please have a look at `ModalNavigationDrawer`, which provides the drawer. You can use your `Scaffold` as a content of the ModalNavigationDrawer.

It seems like this has been split up into multiple components....

Comment: I was doing this since March this year, forgot to update here

Comment: What do you mean by: "You can use your Scaffold as a content."? Could you please explain in more detail, I have the same problem?

Comment: @CodePoet: I wanted to point out that it has been split into two components. ModelNavigationDrawer was added and the functionality has been removed from the Scaffold.

Therefore you need the Scaffold the content (= composable function) of the ModalNavigationDrawer:

M2: `Scaffold { /*more content*/ }`

M3: `ModalNavigationDrawer { Scaffold { /*more content*/ }}`

Does this help?

Comment: The official migration guide also shows how to change your code: [Migration to ModalNavigationDrawer (M2 - M3 Comparison)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#m3_9)

And for completion the link to the [ModalNavigationDrawer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalNavigationDrawer(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DrawerState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0))

Comment: Any idea how to close the ModalNavigationDrawer when the back button is pressed? back button exits the app directly.

Answer (score 4):

Create navigation drawer in Material design 3 with Jetpack compose example using **ModalNavigationDrawer** :

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ModalNavigationDrawerSample() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // icons to mimic drawer destinations
    val items = listOf(Icons.Default.Favorite, Icons.Default.Face, Icons.Default.Email)
val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            Spacer(Modifier.height(12.dp))
            items.forEach { item ->
                NavigationDrawerItem(
                    icon = { Icon(item, contentDescription = null) },
                    label = { Text(item.name) },
                    selected = item == selectedItem.value,
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                        selectedItem.value = item
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                )
            }
        }
    },
    content = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = if (drawerState.isClosed) ">>> Swipe >>>" else "<<< Swipe <<<")
            Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                Text("Click to open")
            }
        }
    }
)
}
```

[image]